# Что за ошибка? TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Tags: python

```
if menu == 1:
    i_point=int(input("Как изменить интелект (+//-)",name_char))
    if i_point+(inte) > 0:
        inte+=i_point
    else:
        print("У вашего персонажа нет столько интелекта")
```

Выводит ошибку: TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2. В чем дело?

Comment: А что такое "name_char"? И как оно используется? Может быть уберете его и все заработает, а? )

Comment: Удалил.
name_char: название создаваемого персонажа.
P.S: Это задача из книги по обучению Python

Comment: Так вам надо к строке "Как изменить интелект (+//-)" имя персонажа добавить?

Так это легко, например:

    "Как изменить интелект (+//-) %s. Текущий уровень: %s" % (name_char, inte)

Или:

    "Как изменить интелект (+//-) {0}. Текущий уровень: {1}".format(name_char, inte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция input принимает 1 аргумент, а вы передаете 2. Второй аргумент лишний.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает!
Хотел, что бы пользователю было понятнее что он делает. Видимо так нельзя.

Comment: @ALPHA, так я же написал (точнее спросил) - что делает "name_char"? Достаточно его убрать - и все будет работать. Т.е. и пользователю понятно - вы сообщение же выводите, и функция работает как надо.

Вы скажите, зачем вам этот "name_char" нужен - тогда может подскажем как его правильно использовать